# Google Maps zoom won't set with function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

So I'm working on my maps here, and for some reason I can't seem to be able to set the zoom when I call a specific function. Here's what I have that does this task:

```
function mapReturn(map){
    $('#job-info').on('click', '#map-return', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(e);
        $('#job-info').css('display' , 'none');
        $('#map-canvas').cass('display', 'block');
        redrawMaps(map);  //redraw maps is very the zoom is suppose to change
        map.fitBounds(bounds);  //global variable bounds not needed here
    });
}

function redrawMaps(map){
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(39.0111, -95.6752);
    map.setZoom(7); //i want the zoom to set here but it won't
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}
```

I'm going to eventually put a logic structure that sets the zoom level based on what you're currently at but for right now I would like it to at least zoom to one level to start with. So to recap, I have a button that returns to the previous view, and when I click it, it zooms all the way out no matter what, I just want it to zoom up to the previous zoom level. Thanks again everyone!

EDIT: To be clear, the code that defines and initializes the map is already set, this is a snippet of the code that is being used, and the only part of the code set that is not functioning correctly. For the sake of completion though:

```
//here are the map options that I used
var mapOptions = {
    center : new google.maps.LatLng(39.0111, -95.6752),
    zoom : 4,
    zoomControl : false,
    panControl : false,
    mapTypeControl : false,
    streetViewControl : false,
    draggable : false,
    scrollWheel : false
};

//here is where I initialize the map object 
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas', mapOptions);
```

Comment: You haven't included the code that defines the map. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: The code to the map is already there and should be implied from the question itself, I'm not posting 300 lines of code. I can if you absolutely want me to, but the relevant pieces to the code are here already.

Comment: A minimal example is not 300 lines of code...

Comment: I gave you a minimal example, I don't see exactly what type of maximum you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `map.setZoom` after triggering the `resize` event (probably need to set the center after the resize as well):

```
function redrawMaps(map){
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(39.0111, -95.6752);
    map.setZoom(7);
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, and I am getting the same result as before. I set something like `var zoom = map.getZoom();` and print it to the console to see if it was set and it did. So the zoom is getting, but not setting, but why wouldn't it. Because it should and resize correct?

Comment: This was a guess, it might have been the issue. I can't tell for sure without a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the issue you are having (which is why i requested one).

Comment: well your guess is somewhat correct, except when I keep the resize in their, the map just goes off center. I suppose I will keep working at it and see what I can come up with.